# Little's MCAR test Chi-Square =.000

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, missing-data, mcar

I am trying to understand the results of my Little's MCAR test (SPSS 26).

Chi-Square = .000, DF = 2113, Sig. = 1.000

As much as I have read articles reporting Little's MCAR test, nobody reports Chi-Square = 0.00 and p = 1.00, so I assume that I have done something wrong. But in youtube tutorials they always get nice and logical numbers, and I have not found discussion about this Chi-Square = 0.000 anywhere.

I don't know if this helps but I'll give a little more background information on my data:

N = 2682; 
There were 58 variables in the analysis, 21 variables had missing data and 37 variables did not. Of the variables that had missing data, two had more than 15 % missing, the rest had 0.1 % - 5.1 % missing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

While it's certainly unusual to see a value of exactly 0 for the chi-square statistic for Little's MCAR test, it's not impossible. It probably means there's something systematic that's ensuring that the means of observed variables for each missing data pattern are the same.